# how to convert matrix output from silhouette() to dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, k-means, silhouette

I ran `kmeans`. I applied `silhouette()` on it. `is.matrix(sil.output)` gives me back a `TRUE`.
so now I must believe I have a matrix. I want to convert it to a dataframe . but `as.data.frame(sil.output)` gives error below. how can I convert the output matrx to data frame.

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(sil) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"silhouette"’ to a data.frame
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `as.data.frame.matrix(sil.output)`.

Alternatively, you can use the other trick of `as.data.frame(sil.output[])`.

Both work as the underlying object is a `matrix`. It's just the class that is causing the issue.